# Is the adress behind this guaruanteed to be identical to a variable with the object

Tags: c++, pointers, raw-pointer

In case of the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

class Sample
{
public:
  Sample* getSelf()
  {
    return this;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Sample s;

  if(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&s) == reinterpret_cast<void*>(s.getSelf()))
    std::cout << "Same address" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Is the condition in the if statement guaruanteed to be true?

I've made the cast to `void*` to be sure that the raw addresses are compared, in case there's some quirks in comparing specific pointer types.

Comment: In your code you misspelled ``reinterpret_cast`` as ``reinterprect_cast`` .

Comment: @appledoes: Do feel empowered to make trivial edits like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes your `if` statement is guaranteed to be `true`. The `this` within `getSelf()` is the pointer to the instance.

And `&s` in `main` is also a pointer to that instance.

The casts are unnecessary as you suspect.